# Sorting objects vector with lambda, not sorting in the end

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, lambda

I'm trying to write a sort function for vectors using lambda, and I've seen this suggested at so many places, but I've always had problems doing this.

```
std::sort(eventvec.begin(), eventvec.end(), [](const event& lhs, const event& rhs) {
    return lhs.getim < rhs.getim;});
```

I had multiple errors while writing it and then I kind of stacked it on a function within a function as it needed a static function.

The functions declared in the class are:

```
double event::getut() { return unift; }

static double getim(event &a) { return a.getut(); }
```

In the end the sorting is not in order at all. There are negative values as well in the attribute. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of errors are there? I think you should be using `return lhs.getim() < rhs.getim();` instead of what you wrote.

Comment: You're not calling the function. `return lhs.getut() < rhs.getut()` but that means you need to make `getut()` const. Like this: `double event::getut() const { return unift; }`

Comment: @TanveerBadar that would ask for arguments, and what do I enter as an argument because lhs.getim(lhs) doesn't work.

Comment: @RetiredNinja error: passing 'const event' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

AND ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
note:   in call to 'double event::getut()'
 double event::getut()
             ^~~~~

Comment: You didn't read all of what I wrote. "that means you need to make getut() const. Like this: `double event::getut() const { return unift; }`"

Comment: @RetiredNinja my bad, the class file was not saved. It worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sorting your events by the address of `event::getim`, which is the same for every event.

I think you mean to call a member function of event, which needs to be callable from a `const event`

```
double event::getut() const { return unift; }

std::sort(eventvec.begin(), eventvec.end(), [](const event& lhs, const event& rhs) {
return lhs.getut() < rhs.getut(); });
```

Comment: @wakanada you need to edit `event::getut` as shown. It needs to be callable from `const event`

Comment: yeah, got it. Thanks